# How can I regenerate the “bash_completions” file from “bash-completion/completions” directory?

Tags: linux, bash, tab-completion

Somehow my `/usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion` file (which is sourced by `/etc/bash_completion`) has been deleted. However, the rest of the `bash-completion` directory appears intact: there is still a `/usr/share/bash-completion/completions` directory with lots of completion-related files.

Is it possible to regenerate the `bash_completion` file from the `completions` directory? Will it work to just `cat` all the files in `completions` together?

**EDIT:** System info:

```
> uname -a
Linux AUC-Workstation2 3.2.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.2.68-1+deb7u1 x86_64 GNU/Linux
> bash --version
GNU bash, version 4.2.37(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to regenerate the `bash_completion` file from the
>   `completions` directory? Will it work to just `cat` all the files in
>   `completions` together?

I'm unsure whether you could regenerate it the way you describe, but you could clone the `bash-completion` source from [the official Debian repository](http://anonscm.debian.org/cgit/bash-completion/bash-completion.git/) like this:

```
git clone git://anonscm.debian.org/cgit/bash-completion/bash-completion.git
```

And once that is cloned, right in the root of that directory is the file you need:

```
bash_completion
```

Or just get the `bash_completion` file itself directly [by browsing the `bash-completion` repository source tree right here](http://anonscm.debian.org/cgit/bash-completion/bash-completion.git/tree/bash_completion).

Whatever method you decide to us, just copy that file into place to `/usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion` on your system, reboot (or perhaps simply log out and log back in again?) and you should be good to go.

Comment: That worked just fine. Thanks. I submitted an edit to fix your `git clone` command, though (you forgot the `/cgit/`).